# Is Day trading (cryptocurrency) haram?

Tags: finance, trading

I've read that buying and selling of something you don't possess is haram however cryptocurrency is different than stocks trading as you don't have to wait for t+2 days for the settlement of the stock. As soon as you buy the crypto in spot you have full ownership of the currency.